# Setting default option with Select2 remote loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using the Select2 library to remote load data via ajax.  However, I'd also like to provide a default option "all".  Right now it's easy enough for me to augment the "results" array with an {name: 'All', id: 'all'} object, and I can make it so 'All' is initially selected, but what I want is that somebody sees 'All' as an option even before they've entered the minimum input length.

Is that possible?  Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: This answer applies to Select2 3.5.2 or earlier. The solution for Select2 4.0 would use a DataAdapter.

You can supply a custom `query` function. When implementing this function, you can use the Select2 `ajax` function since it is publicly exposed.

```
var ALL_OPTION = { id: 'ALL', text: 'All' };

$('#select').select2({
    _minimumInputLength: 2,
    _ajaxQuery: Select2.query.ajax({
        // Place all your ajax options here, as if you were using
        // the Select2 "ajax" option.
    }),
    query: function(options) {
        if (options.term.length >= this._minimumInputLength) {
            this._ajaxQuery.call(this, options);
        } else {
            options.callback({ results: [ALL_OPTION] });
        }
    }
});
```

You can't use the `minimumInputLength` option because it will prevent the `query` function from getting called. Instead, the code above uses an option named `_minimumInputLength` inside the `query` function. This means, however, that you will not get the "Please enter 2 or more characters" message in the drop down. (Unless you implement it yourself somehow.)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gga737qq/1/)

---

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gga737qq/3/) that implements the "Please enter 2 or more characters" message.

Comment: great! I'm going to test this today and then mark this answer as correct if it works.  It certainly looks good, thanks John!

Comment: Can you provide an example of using Select2 4.0 to do this behavior? It does not seem to work for me.